# In scripts and css, do the symbols /* */ increase filesize like blankspaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to minify css and javascript code, and I am just wondering whether the symbols /* and */ and the characters within them count in terms of html, css and javascript **filesizes** or if they are just ignored.

Would that mean that I could replace all the single blankspaces with /* */ to decrease the total **filesize**?

For instance, which of these 3 examples would be most efficient, and most inefficient in this regard?

Example 1: (Single blankspace between functions)

```
$("#div1").click(function(){$("#div2").slideToggle();return false;});

$("#button1").click(function() {$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#destination").offset().top}, 1000);});
```

Example 2:

```
$("#div1").click(function(){$("#div2").slideToggle();return false;});
/* */
$("#button1").click(function() {$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#destination").offset().top}, 1000);});
```

Example 3:

```
$("#div1").click(function(){$("#div2").slideToggle();return false;});/* Clicking on div2 slidetoggles div2. */
/* */
$("#button1").click(function() {$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#destination").offset().top}, 1000);});/* Clicking on button1 scrolls you to destination. */
```

I assume that having all code on 1 line would be most efficient, but I just included these examples since I would like to maintain some readability for certain code and css. I know that there are a lot of **minifying tools online**, but right now I would prefer not to use one, since I edit code daily, and am still very much in the learning process.

Would example 2-3 account have the same effect on **filesize**? Or would actually a single blankspace be more efficient?

Comment: I've always thought that minifying removes most whitespace and all comments, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: What the intent of reducing the filesize?  Couple of reasons could be: 1. reduce disk space usage (real old-school reason).  2 reduce transmission time to the client.  3. mung the scripts so your successor is setup to fail.  4. purely intellectual  5. some other reason

Comment: @freedomn-m 2. reduce transmission time to clients.

Comment: That seemed the most likely.  Short answer, don't bother, keep your code maintainable.  Unless you're serving 10of1000s *unique* visitors a day on a dial-up connection and you pay per byte - this kind of micro-optimisation is not worth the time and the benefit you get from keeping it readable (=maintainable) will vastly outweigh any perceived benefit saved from a few bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of **processing** the files, all comments and non-important white spaces are properly ignored by the parser.

But in terms of file size, that is what matters when we're talking about files being transferred through the internet (which is the case of html, css and js files), **every single character counts**.

That's why your website is faster if you minify all the assets, because they are smaller to **transfer**, not to process.

Always keep in mind, however, that when you are developing you can put all comments, white spaces and what you think is necessary in sake of understanding of the code, and you should minify the resources just when it's about to go to production. Don't try to minify your code by yourself, always use tools that have some experience on the job, like [this minifier for JavaScript](http://javascript-minifier.com/).

---

> I assume that having all code on 1 line would be most efficient, but I
>   just included these examples since I would like to maintain some
>   readability for certain code and css. I know that there are a lot of
>   minifying tools online, but right now I would prefer not to use one,
>   since I edit code daily, and am still very much in the learning
>   process.

Do **NOT** compromise your code readability in order to achieve less filesize. Write your code clearly and use market stablished minifying tools.

If you change the code quite often, automatize the process of minifying using tools like CSS pre-processors ([Less](http://lesscss.org/) pre-processor with [clean-css plugin](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-clean-css), for example). I have my NetBeans and VisualStudio configured to compile and minify all my CSS using Less + clean-css when I save them. It's easy to configure and really useful.

Some frameworks even offer functionalities or have plugins to help you handling this kind of problems. As an example, one can cite the [asset-pipeline plugin](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline) for PHP [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) framework

Comment: Ok, I slightly edited my question to clarify that I would like to find the most efficient ways in terms of reducing filesize. So in other words, would example 2 cause a larger filesize than example 1, since it has more characters?

Comment: Exactly. Actually, even a line-break is composed of 1 or even 2 "characters" (ASCI codes 10 and 13). I'll edit my answer to clarify the new questions you made.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you write code that is easy to read and then minimize it with a specialized tool.

The reason is that the priority is on developing code that runs well.  Adapting good code for high performance is a secondary issue.  A good minification tool can reduce the length of variable names, strip out comments and whitespace.

Another alternative is to just gzip those files when they are delivered to the client.  The gains of compression will far outweigh any attempts to remove content from the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove as much whitespace, comments and such as possible to decrease the size of you file since it will make the loading faster. Of couse you should not need to think about this during development since things are all about readability, maintainabily, etc. at that stage.

Mangling your code can do a lot to your file size as well. This means that variable names are truncated to names like a,b,c for example.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to minimalize, put everything in one line without comments. Other way You just making useless changes. If You want to now if Your changes makes diffrences, look at file size of css or js. Those files are send as they are on server.